# How to execute different code on different actions (GET , POST , DELETE) in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my index method in the home controller. I have a submission form on the index page and I only want the code to run when they hit the submit button. I'm used to webforms so I'm a little stuck on this problem if you can please offer some advice.

```
public ActionResult Index(EssayInfoModels c)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            // attempting to load the dropdownlist with choices here but it fails when the page first loads because there is nothing in it yet.
            if (c.topicList.Count == 0)
            {
                c.topicList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Math", Value = "Math" });
                c.topicList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Science", Value = "Science" });
            }


            // send message code here
            return View("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]`

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View()
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(EssayInfoModels c)
{
   // YOUR CODE
   return View()
}
```

Comment: Those attributes are case sensitive... It's `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpGet]`

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, i'm a little shocked that you're having this problem.  This is pretty basic, and would be explained in the very first steps of almost any tutorial.  However, be that as it may...

You would use attributes to create a Get and Post method.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index() {
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(EssayInfoModels c)
{
    // process your posted data...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have another Index method with an attribute [HttpPost] as below

```
public ActionResult Index() --> Get Action of Index
{
   ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public string Index(FormCollection fc) --> Triggers when you click a button (POST action)
{
    return "In post Index";
}
```

To activate this function you must have form in your Index View as below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="submit" value="click" />
}
```

so, when you click on this button it will trigger [HttpPost] action of Index